# SRAM Red 53/39 10spd rings and 172.5 crank work with 11 speed cassette upgrade?

Tags: road-bike, crankset, chainring

I want to upgrade my 10 speed to 11. Will my SRAM Red 53/39 10spd rings and 172.5 crank work with an 11 speed upgrade? Looking to upgrade to SRAM eTap with the "kit". I understand the need for a new cassette (11-28), front & rear derailleurs, shifters and 11 speed chain.  Do I need new crank and chainrings?

Comment: 11-speed chain is narrower than 10-speed. You keep the crank but you must put on 11-speed rings.

Comment: @carel that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: A bit short for an answer @Criggie don't you think?

Comment: @Carel there's not a lot to say, but SE's guideline is that comments are  for discussing the question and getting clarification about the question.   Answers are answers.   I do the same too when I lack time for a fully fleshed, researched, and illustrated answer.

Answer (score 1):

11-speed chain is narrower than 10-speed. You keep the crank but you must put on 11-speed rings which will most certainly fit judging by the pictures on SRAM's website. The shape of the cranks remains the same and the BCD is identical, of course.

Comment: Isn't it only the outside width that has changed between 10 and 11 speed? Why would your chainrings care about the outside width of the chain? Based on [this source](http://www.velonews.com/2016/01/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/tech-faq-chain-width-explained-compatibility-queries-answered_392163) the inner width for all chains from my understanding is 3/32.

Comment: It could be worth the trial. At least his says that there are different sizes of 10-speed chains: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain

Comment: outside width of chain matters for shifting, how far the chain must be pushed/what shape it is when it contacts the shift ramps.  As mentioned in the article, the difference is not huge and it will "probably still work good enough"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article about it

http://www.velonews.com/2013/11/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-follow-up-on-10-and-11-speed-compatibility_307163

So, you cannot technically run an 11 speed chain on 10 speed chain rings. As the article says, the chain rings can be swapped out and you can keep the same cranks from your 10 speed set up.

From my own experience however you can run 11 speed chain on 10 speed chainrings, but as advised by SRAM, the shifting is not great, eg. you will get chainsuck and slow shifting occasionally

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help and info. Always worth a try and change to 11 chainrings if needed later.